# Load a hidden terminal buffer

Tags: neovim

When I restore a session containing terminal buffers, terminal buffers (like other kinds of buffers) don't load while they're hidden. Is there any way to load them in background without making them active so that they run their processes? (I want to change their state from inactive to hidden without ever making their state active - `:help active-buffer`).